# Node JS -Telegram bot works locally but not on heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku, telegram-bot

My telegram bot working perfectly on local machine but when I deploy it to heroku it become unresponsive and dynos are also set to npm start even when I declared start script in package.json.Here is the log file:-

2022-06-04T15:45:02.232005+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:547:31)
2022-06-04T15:45:02.232006+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Promise._settlePromise (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:604:18)
2022-06-04T15:45:02.232006+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Promise._settlePromise0 (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:649:10)
2022-06-04T15:45:02.232006+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Promise._settlePromises (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:729:18)
2022-06-04T15:45:02.232006+00:00 app[web.1]:     at _drainQueueStep (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:93:12)
2022-06-04T15:45:02.232007+00:00 app[web.1]:     at _drainQueue (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:86:9)
2022-06-04T15:45:02.232007+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Async._drainQueues (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:102:5)
2022-06-04T15:45:02.232008+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:15:14)
2022-06-04T15:45:02.232011+00:00 app[web.1]:     at processImmediate (node:internal/timers:466:21)
2022-06-04T15:45:02.521059+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up

edit- The code is shared below, I followed a tutorial to make my own telegram bot

```
    const TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api');
    const axios = require('axios');
    // This file would be created soon
    
     
    require('dotenv').config();
     
    const token = "token is here";
    let bot;
     
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
       bot = new TelegramBot(token);
       bot.setWebHook(process.env.HEROKU_URL + bot.token);
    } else {
       bot = new TelegramBot(token, { polling: true });
    }
    
    bot.onText(/\/word (.+)/, (msg, match) => {
        const chatId = msg.chat.id;
        const word = match[1];
        bot.sendMessage(chatId, "NO");
      });
    
      const express = require('express')
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
     
    const app = express();
             
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
     
    app.listen(process.env.PORT);

    app.post('/' + bot.token, (req, res) => {
      bot.processUpdate(req.body);
      res.sendStatus(200);
    });
```

Comment: The logs indicates a problem with the promise, but commenting without seeing the code can be a bit absurd. According to what you said, it works locally but not on Heroku, maybe there is a problem with your environment variables. If you can give more details I might be able to help.

Comment: the code is shared in the edited post

Comment: I don't see any problem in the code. Since it's running locally, you're probably having trouble defining the "HEROKU_URL" and/or "PORT" environment variable. Did you define these two variables in the .env file or did you give them as configuration via Heroku?

Comment: I posted an article on below link. At the bottom, there is the section about publishing bots on Heroku. The article is in Turkish, but maybe you can infer from the pictures. Blog: https://medium.com/@fatiiates/telegram-chatbot-w-python-heroku-6bdbe045fb8

Comment: Thanks for your help The error is due to misconfigured Heroku URL variable